# How to fix [CRITICAL] App.root must be an _instance_ of Widget

Tags: python, kivy, instance, traceback, critical-section

[image: Error in command line terminal]

I was working on kivy to learn to build apps. I am encountering this error while running the attached code.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyGrid,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Name:"))
        self.name=TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.name)


class MyApp(App):
     def build(self):
    return MyGrid

if __name__== "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: try `return MyGrid()` instead of `MyGrid`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace return MyGrid ----> return MyGrid()